# How to solve this query Error

Tags: c#, winforms, ms-access

How can I get this query to work? keep getting this error:

> "syntax error in INSERT INTO statement"

I am confused as it used to work on another program, but I got all scrambled up with this one.

```
 string item = listView1.Items[listView1.FocusedItem.Index].Text;
 MessageBox.Show(item); //test Value

 string thisDay1 = DateTime.Now.ToString();

 ad.InsertCommand = new OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO Scrap-Rework Master Data (Is_today, S_Line, Status, T_Number, Test_Cp, think_a, Rew_Hos, QAffect, Comments) 
    values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)", con);

ad.InsertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@S_Line", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = textBox1.Text;
ad.InsertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Status", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = domainUpDown1.Text;
ad.InsertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@T_Number", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = textBox2.Text;
ad.InsertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Test_Cp", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = item;
ad.InsertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@think_a", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = domainUpDown2.Text;
ad.InsertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Rew_Hos", OleDbType.Numeric).Value = Double.Parse(textBox4.Text);
ad.InsertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@QAffect", OleDbType.Numeric).Value = int.Parse(textBox3.Text);
ad.InsertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Comments", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = textBox5.Text;
ad.InsertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Is_today", OleDbType.DBTime).Value = thisDay1;
```

Listview has 2  columns:

```
ListViewItem listitem = new ListViewItem(dr["Test_Cp"].ToString());
 listitem.SubItems.Add(dr["Description"].ToString());
```

fields on access database and type:

```
S_Line          -Short Text;    
Status          -Short Text;    
T_Number        -Short Text;    
Test_Cp         -Short Text;    
think_a         -Short Text;    
Rew_Hos         -Number;    
QAffect         -Number;    
Comments        -Long Text;    
Is_today        -Date/Time;
```

Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: What is the name of the table you're inserting into? If its "Scrap-Rework Master Data" with spaces, you need to qualify the name in square brackets e.g. insert into [Scrap-Rework Master Data]

Comment: Your parameters in the SQL (the `?`s) aren't named. If OleDbCommand supports that, and assumes they're assembled using your argument order, then it won't work because the IsToday is out of sequence.

Comment: OleDB ignores the parameter name, so your parameters have to be in index order.  That means your `@Is_today` parameter would have to be added first since that's the first `?` in the query expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you must use brackets [] always for the name that contains spaces in query like `[Scrap-Rework Master Data]`.

2- Declare `OleDbCommand` parameter.

3- Put name of `Parameters` in query with respect order.

4- Format `DateTime` field.

5- add `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();` for insert data.

```
string item = listView1.Items[listView1.FocusedItem.Index].Text;
MessageBox.Show(item); //test Value

OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO [Scrap-Rework Master Data] (S_Line, Status, T_Number, Test_Cp, think_a, Rew_Hos, QAffect, Comments, Is_today)" +
                                     "values(@S_Line, @Status, @T_Number, @Test_Cp, @think_a, @Rew_Hos, @QAffect, @Comments, @Is_today)", con);

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@S_Line", textBox1.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Status", domainUpDown1.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@T_Number", textBox2.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Test_Cp", item) ;
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@think_a", domainUpDown2.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Rew_Hos", Double.Parse(textBox4.Text)) ;
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@QAffect", int.Parse(textBox3.Text)) ;
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Comments", textBox5.Text) ;
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Is_today", DateTime.Now.ToString("#yyyy/MM/dd#"));

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Answer (score 1):

You're using OleDB, so you [can't use named parameters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yy6y35y8(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_1):

> System.Data.OleDb 
>   Uses positional parameter markers indicated by a question mark (?).

which means (from same page)

> As a result, the order in which Parameter objects are added to the Parameters collection must directly correspond to the position of the ? placeholder for the parameter.

The problem is your order is wrong: the first value in your INSERT is Is_Today, but that's the last value you add to the parameter array. Hence all the value types are wrong. Try moving

```
ad.InsertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Is_today", OleDbType.DBTime).Value = thisDay1;
```

to the head of your parameter add list.

Also I agree with [abrown's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37335914/how-to-solve-this-query-error#comment62189492_37335914): you'll likely need to bracket the table name `[Scrap-Rework Master Data]` since it has spaces and a dash in it.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use stored procedure in DB:

```
using (var command1 = new SqlCommand("InsertData", conn)
{
    CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
})
{
    command1.Parameters.Add("@a1", SqlDbType.Text).Value = A1;
    command1.Parameters.Add("@a2", SqlDbType.Text).Value = A2;
    command1.Parameters.Add("@a3", SqlDbType.Text).Value = A3;
    command1.Parameters.Add("@a4", SqlDbType.Text).Value = A4;

    command1.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```